# Some questions on the existence of Right-sided Limit of a Decreasing Function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f:(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a decreasing function, bounded below. Show that $\lim\limits_{x\downarrow a}f(x)$ exists. This is the proof of the exercise I have but I have some problems with it.

Since $f$ is bounded below, by completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ we have $\inf\limits_{a<x<b}f(x):=L\in\mathbb{R}$, and then the claim is $\lim\limits_{x\downarrow a}f(x)=L$, i.e. $(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0)(\forall x)(0<x-a<\delta\Rightarrow|f(x)-L|<\epsilon)$. So take an $\epsilon>0$ then as $L$ is a lower bound, $L-\epsilon<L\leq f(x)$, for any $a<x<b$; and as $L$ is the infimum for this $\epsilon$, $\exists y\in(a,b)$ such that $f(y)<L+\epsilon$. Then as $f$ is decreasing we have $(\forall x)(a<y<x<b\Rightarrow f(x)\leq f(y)\leq L+\epsilon)$, so taking $\delta=y-a$ we have proved the claim.

My 1st gripe is why is the choice of $\inf\limits_{a<x<b}f(x)=L$? I think this is a mistake, as $f$ is decreasing so than surley as $x\downarrow a$ we have $f\uparrow$, so shouldn't it be that $\lim\limits_{x\downarrow a}f(x)\geq f(x)$, $\forall x\in(a,b)$. So maybe the premise is wrong and they should of assumed that $f$ is bounded from above then looked at the supremum?

My 2nd gripe is the choice of $\delta=y-a$, as this then implies that $x<y$ and as $f$ is decreasing we have $f(y)\leq f(x)$ so how can we say $f(x)<L+\epsilon$, if all we know is that $f(y)<L+\epsilon$, surely we must have $y<x$ to make the claim?

Please can anyone give me some input as to whether the above proof is right or wrong and if my grievances are valid. If they are not please can you explain where I am wrong. Any help and feedback will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are right with all your doubts. Both of the things you do not understand are wrong in the "solution" of the exercise.